# MFC application works in Visual Studio but crashes with double click launch

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, crash, ntdll

I have a GUI application in `MFC`. For some reason, it works perfectly fine within Visual Studio Release and Debug mode, but crashes if the `.exe` is launched with a double click.

I cannot understand where this error could be, since it works perfectly fine when hosted in Visual Studio. In desperation, I disabled all Optimization routines but it does not seem to have helped.

`OS` is `Win 7`,`IDE` is `VS 2010`.

The faulting module is `ntdll.dll`, but I doubt it is the real issue...

**EDIT -**

Attaching the debugger to the crash shows a problem with `LoadFrame()`

```
BOOL CAAUserInterfaceDllConsumerApp::InitInstance()
{
    // InitCommonControlsEx() is required on Windows XP if an application
    // manifest specifies use of ComCtl32.dll version 6 or later to enable
    // visual styles.  Otherwise, any window creation will fail.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    // Set this to include all the common control classes you want to use
    // in your application.
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    CWinAppEx::InitInstance();


    EnableTaskbarInteraction(FALSE);

    // AfxInitRichEdit2() is required to use RichEdit control   
    // AfxInitRichEdit2();

    // Standard initialization
    // If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the size
    // of your final executable, you should remove from the following
    // the specific initialization routines you do not need
    // Change the registry key under which our settings are stored
    // TODO: You should modify this string to be something appropriate
    // such as the name of your company or organization
    SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));

    DWORD isApprunning = 0;

    m_hStartMutex = CreateSemaphore(NULL,
                                    1,
                                    1,
                                    _T("Something"));

    if (GetLastError() ==  ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
        // I dont want to start !
        return FALSE;
    }

    InitContextMenuManager();

    InitKeyboardManager();

    InitTooltipManager();
    CMFCToolTipInfo ttParams;
    ttParams.m_bVislManagerTheme = TRUE;
    theApp.GetTooltipManager()->SetTooltipParams(AFX_TOOLTIP_TYPE_ALL,
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCToolTipCtrl), &ttParams);

    // To create the main window, this code creates a new frame window
    // object and then sets it as the application's main window object
    CMainFrame* pFrame = new CMainFrame;
    if (!pFrame)
        return FALSE;
    m_pMainWnd = pFrame;
    // create and load the frame with its resources
    pFrame->LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | FWS_ADDTOTITLE, NULL,
        NULL);
      .//more stuff
}
```

This calls :

```
BOOL CMainFrame::LoadFrame(UINT nIDResource, DWORD dwDefaultStyle, CWnd* pParentWnd, CCreateContext* pContext) 
{
    // base class does the real work

    //if (!CFrameWndEx::LoadFrame(nIDResource, dwDefaultStyle, pParentWnd, pContext))
    if (!CFrameWndEx::LoadFrame(nIDResource, dwDefaultStyle, pParentWnd, pContext))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

And here is where it fails outside of Visual Studio.

The Exception given is  : `The activation context being deactivated is not the most recently activated one`.

I searched around and tried the following, i.e., set all `Exceptions` to throw to catch any handled exception, and setting `afxAmbientActCtx` to `FALSE`, but no luck getting it to run. This `exe` used to run just fine before.

Kindly advise.

Comment: One easy way to reproduce that problem is to make behavior depend on the current working directory.

Comment: When the application crashes attach the debugger to it. Look into the call stack.

Comment: I've done the same and attached the code.